# How do I create a psycopg2 SQL insert statement to handle multiple data types from streaming data

Tags: python, postgresql, typeerror, psycopg2

```
dicts = [{"timestamp": "2021-03-05T18:16:36.178Z", "symbol": "USD", "side": "Sell", "size": 20, "price": 1522.55, "tickDirection": "ZeroMinusTick", "trdMatchID": "a7ecffce-74be-bedc-3f7d-b2deff9187f3", "grossValue": 3045100, "homeNotional": 0.9685230024213075, "foreignNotional": 1474.6246973365617}...]
for index in range(len(dicts)):
    for key, value in dicts[index].items():
        sql_insert_data = "INSERT INTO flow(timestamp, symbol, side, size, price, 
        tickdirection, trdmatchid, grossvalue, homenotional, foreignnotional) VALUES(%(timestamp)s, % 
        (str)s, %(str)s, %(int)s, %(int)s, %(str)s, %(str)s, %(int)s, %(int)s, %(int)s);"
        
        cursor.execute(sql_insert_data, value)
        connection.commit()
```

This is a backend process to:

- Capture streaming JSON objects (10 items) from a Python dictionary,
- Parse keys to PostgreSQL table columns with the same names and
- Commit each set of corresponding values into a row.

I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 0):

The names for your substitution have to match the keys in your dictionary, not the type.  I know the example in the Psycopg2 documentation is a bit misleading.

```
dicts = [{"timestamp": "2021-03-05T18:16:36.178Z", "symbol": "USD", "side": "Sell", "size": 20, "price": 1522.55, "tickDirection": "ZeroMinusTick", "trdMatchID": "a7ecffce-74be-bedc-3f7d-b2deff9187f3", "grossValue": 3045100, "homeNotional": 0.9685230024213075, "foreignNotional": 1474.6246973365617}...]

sql_insert_data = "INSERT INTO flow(timestamp, symbol, side, size, price, 
    tickdirection, trdmatchid, grossvalue, homenotional, foreignnotional)
    VALUES( %(timestamp)s, 
    %(symbol)s, %(side)s, %(size)s, %(price)s, %(tickdirection)s, %(trmatchid)s,
    %(grossvalue)s, %(homenotional)s, %(foreignnotional)s);"

for dict in dicts:        
    cursor.execute(sql_insert_data, dict)
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response! Unfortunately the changes introduce a new error in my code ( `for key, value in dict: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).  I agree with you the documentation can be confusing.  All that said, I feel like I'm getting closer.

Comment: You're right, let me fix it.  It needed to be dict.items().

Comment: I know, that's what I thought but when I added it I got the original Typeerror.

Comment: EXACTLY where do you see that error?  What line?

Comment: Thanks for hanging with this Tim.  I'm getting the error at `cursor.execute(sql_insert_data, value)`.

Comment: I found this paragraph while researching potential issues: The SQL representation of many data types is often different from their Python string representation. The typical example is with single quotes in strings: in SQL single quotes are used as string literal delimiters, so the ones appearing inside the string itself must be escaped, whereas in Python single quotes can be left unescaped if the string is delimited by double quotes.

Comment: The only research you need to do is this [Adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) where you will find that `psycopg2` does the heavy lifting for you.  As to the paragraph you mention,  in that same section is: 'Psycopg can automatically convert Python objects to and from SQL literals: using this feature your code will be more robust and reliable. We must stress this point:"

Comment: I think you'll need to triple-check that all of the types in the dictionary match the types of the fields in the SQL schema.  Maybe you're passing an integer to something that wants a string.

Comment: I think it is more because this; `for key, value in dict.items(): ...  cursor.execute(sql_insert_data, value)` is bound to fail. `sql_insert_data` is looking to have an entire dict passed to it, not individual items.

Comment: Doggone it, that's right.  Let me fix it.  My answer is now the same as Adrians.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sql_insert_data = "INSERT INTO flow(timestamp, symbol, side, size, price, 
        tickdirection, trdmatchid, grossvalue, homenotional, foreignnotional)
        VALUES( %(timestamp)s, 
        %(symbol)s, %(side)s, %(size)s, %(price)s, %(tickdirection)s, %(trmatchid)s,
        %(grossvalue)s, %(homenotional)s, %(foreignnotional)s);"

dict_list = [{"timestamp": "2021-03-05T18:16:36.178Z", "symbol": "USD", "side": "Sell", "size": 20, "price": 1522.55, "tickDirection": "ZeroMinusTick", "trdMatchID": "a7ecffce-74be-bedc-3f7d-b2deff9187f3", "grossValue": 3045100, "homeNotional": 0.9685230024213075, "foreignNotional": 1474.6246973365617}...]

for dict in dict_list:
     cursor.execute(sql_insert_data, dict)
     con.commit()
```

Once you have set up the named parameters in the query string you can pass the entire dict to the query in `execute` and it will match the named parameters to the dict keys and use that key's value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Adrian I will try it shortly. I've been acting on the link you provided in the comments earlier - it has been helpful, but is forcing me to look more deeply into the issues.

Comment: You're over thinking this. The data looks clean. Try the example and then see if there are issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error `cursor.execute(sql_insert_data, dicx) KeyError: 'tickdirection' ` I'm at a loss because it should work. I've been looking into encoding / adaption errors but haven't founding anything.  Fyi, the columns in the db are all type: text except for timestamp (timestamptz) size(integer) price and grossvalue (numeric), other number columns are type: real. I also created a new database...same issue ocurred.

Comment: You need to show exactly what you did. Add this to your question as an UPDATE. Best guess `dicx` does not contain: `{ ..., 'tickdirection': some_value, ...}`. Again you are over thinking, look at the error. It is telling you this a dict error, not a type problem.

Comment: Agreed - I actually have it partially working now(its loading the first 5 of 10 values).  As soon as I get it fully functional I'll clean everything in this post up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Roberts and Adrian Klaver who provided me with solid guidance for solving this problem.  There were issues on both the data source side and postgresql db side that had to be handled before the code below would work.

```
dict_list = [{"timestamp": "2021-03-05T18:16:36.178Z", "symbol": "USD", "side": "Sell", "size": 20, "price": 1522.55, "tickDirection": "ZeroMinusTick", "trdMatchID": "a7ecffce-74be-bedc-3f7d-b2deff9187f3", "grossValue": 3045100, "homeNotional": 0.9685230024213075, "foreignNotional": 1474.6246973365617}...]

 sql_in = "INSERT INTO flow(timestamp, symbol, side, size, price, tickdirection, trdmatchid, grossvalue, homenotional, foreignnotional) VALUES ( %(timestamp)s, %(symbol)s, %(side)s, %(size)s, %(price)s, %(tickDirection)s, %(trdMatchID)s, %(grossValue)s, %(homeNotional)s, %(foreignNotional)s );"

    for dicx in dict_list:
        cursor.execute(sql_in, dicx)
        connection.commit()
```

Some notes about the issues requiring resolution:

- Unicode adaption: Make sure all incoming data is encoded properly. Because of the nature of my data sources I used utf-8.
- There are important differences between char, number and datetime data types and you need to make sure you choose ones that work in python, psycopg2 and postgresql. For example originally I used the timestamp data type, then text for the 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.msZ' format, which appeared to be a {str} according to the debugger. Based on the guidance of this wiki, [postgresql - Don't Do This & Why Not](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Why_not.3F)! the recommended timestamptz worked; even though there was no time zone data. I used numeric for $ values and text for character types, as there was not performance benefit between text and other char types. This page was also a valuable resource [Adapting Python to SQL Data Types](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/psycopg2/2.7.3/usage.html#python-types-adaptation).
- The Postgresql table column names were lower case but the %(placeHolder)s were camelCase. I had to make the %(placeholder)s names lower case to match the columns for it to work on my system; anything different threw a syntax error.  This error was difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes there was time zone data, the 'Z' in the string. Also using `timestamptz` means the incoming data is rotated to UTC using that, in this case a no-op. If there had been no time zone or offset it would have rotated using the server `TimeZone` setting.  If you use named parameters (%(some_name)s) you are using a dictionary to do the look up. Therefore dict rules apply, the lookup has to match the key. There is no requirement that the column names and parameter names match, just that the number of values provided match the number of columns and that the values match the column types.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian - I'm not 100% sure the Z alone means time zone.  Time zones are denoted with a, eg. + 08 UTC suffix.  As for the matching column names, I agree I don't (or at least didn't) think it would matter, but at one point I had 5 of the 10 columns working. The diff was the 5 working matched. When I made all 10 match they all started working...weird I know. Maybe a psycopg2 thing - it was a very difficult issue to troubleshoot. In any case, thank you so much for all your input!

Comment: I'm 100% sure, see here [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): 'If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "T0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "T144515Z". '.

Comment: It is not a `psycopg2` thing it is a dictionary thing, the parameter name has to match a dictionary key. The built query has two parts, the actual column list in `flow(...)` which must match the column names in the table and the parameter names in `VALUES(...)` that match the keys in `dicx`.